# Android Edittext topleft and topright only rounded

Tags: android

I want to have 3 edittext with top and bottom having topleft and topright curves but bottom-left and bottom-right straight. I tried to use shape

but it makes all the corners curved. If i try to use bottomRightRadius, then i get exception.

So I tried different way of doing it

using -ve margin so that bottom on hides the upper one's curve. But now bottom one is going behind  the upper one. There is nothing like goToBottom or goToTop :(

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set radius of corners you want to see not rounded to the value near to 0 (but not 0):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#eeffffff" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dip"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dip"  android:topRightRadius="0.1dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="0.1dip"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the android:radius attribute to at least 1dip in order to get any rounded corner displayed.

Then you go like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners
        android:radius="1dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dip"
        android:topRightRadius="10dip"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dip"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dip" />
</shape>
```

You save this as your background.xml in the drawable subdir. Then you set it as the EditText's background using

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

This should get you your desired output.